# How do you store raw and jpg files separately

Tags: file-management, photoshop-cs5

I shoot in raw and jpg but when I'm done I just want to give the customer all the jpg files and keep the raw files so I can do some touch up on the ones they want.

I want to store it in different folders so that I can just select of the jpg images all at once and not the raw companion files.

What workflow/techniques could fulfill my needs?

Comment: This is very operating-system dependent, and possibly also dependent on the workflow software you use, if any. Can you give some more detail?

Comment: I think there are cameras with two card slots which can put raw on one card and jpg on the other. However for this special case you should probably look for a solution in your computer (e.g. sorting or some simple software) and not in your camera.

Answer (score 3):

I've never heard of a camera that does that. If there is one, it should be mentioned in your camera manual.

The simplest alternative is probably to click the *Type* heading at the top of Windows explorer (or the equivalent in your OS/app of choice) to sort by file type.  This will put all of your RAW files together and all of your JPGs together, for easy selection and copy/drag.

[image]

Comment: Cameras with more than one card slot offer the option to dump RAW to one, JPG to the second. My D7000 offers this as an option.

Answer (score 3):

These days I shoot RAW only (and use Lightroom).    If I needed to produce the things you do here, I would continue to shoot RAW only, and colour-correct the images immediately after input.   Export all the images and give those to the client.   Then when they've selected the images the like, edit those further.    None of these steps need to use an out-of-camera JPG.

For me the advantage of doing things this way is that there would be no extraneous JPG files around the place, and I don't get into an argument with the client about why my edited image doesn't look like the out-of-camera JPG file.

Answer (score 1):

Set your camera to 'Record Separately' and select L, M or S for one card and select RAW or SRAW for the other card. Then copy one card for customer and other card for you.

If only one card at a time in camera, then could use 'Command Prompt'. Like:

```
C:\> COPY F:\DCIM\100CANON\*.JPG C:\CUSTOMER\JOHNDOE
C:\> COPY F:\DCIM\100CANON\*.CR2 C:\MYPHOTOS\JOHNDOE
```

You must change paths according to your computer.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of simplicity for yourself, the simplest approach is to shoot just RAW, then go through the images using Lightroom/Bridge/Canon's Digital Photo Professional/etc. and edit the ones you consider editing worthy and leave the ones you think are fine.

Then just batch convert all image - which you can then stick in a dedicated folder (say called JPEG) which can be in the image folder with the RAWs.

Obviously if you want to give images to your clients immediately, this won't work, however the benefit of the above approach is that it is more streamlined than fiddling around with in camera JPEG and RAW and then sort through both. (There was a time when I was shooting both and when I tidied up, I binned the JPEGs because they are useless - using dedicated software will give you a higher quality JPEG than using the camera.)
The other advantage of doing the JPEG conversion later is that you can decide how big or small the JPEGs should be - i.e. you can say limit the width to 1000 pixels and give those out as previews.

Having said all of that, it is really the photographers job to sort through the images and edit them.  It is quite likely that many people will be disappointed if they see the RAW output from an SLR and will only really appreciate the image after it has been edited. SLRs do not sharpen and saturate images as much as compact cameras do - but people got used to the look of such photos.

Answer (score 0):

In Adobe Bridge there is the option of filtering by image type. This way you can hide the RAW files.